# How to prevent fullscreen/halfscreen on Windows

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, fullscreen, wndproc

I am developing a single-window app on Windows with Unity.
I allow a user to resize the window but the aspect ratio must be kept.
I want to prevent fullscreen and halfscreen, because they break the aspect ratio.

I've found the following operations make an app fullscreen or halfscreen.

- fullscreen:

  - clicking a maximize button on the title bar
  - dragging the window to top of screen
  - pressing Alt + Enter key
  - pressing Windows + Up-Arrow key
- halfscreen:

  - dragging the window to left/right of screen
  - pressing Windows + Left/Right -Arrow key

I want to disable all of them.

This can disable a maximize button on the title bar.

```cs
HandleRef hWnd = new HandleRef(null, GetActiveWindow());
long style = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
style &= ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX;
SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, style);
```

And this can disable Windows + Up-Arrow key.

```cs
private static IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
            if (wParam.ToInt32() == SC_MAXIMIZE) {
                return IntPtr.Zero;
            }
            break;
    }

    return CallWindowProc(oldWndProcPtr, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

But the other operations still work.
How can I disable the other operations?

Answer (score -1):

```
private static IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
            if (wParam.ToInt32() == SC_MAXIMIZE) {
                return IntPtr.Zero;
            }
            break;
        // BY PASS *** Alt + Enter ***
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
            if (wParam == VK_RETURN)
                if ((HIWORD(lParam) & KF_ALTDOWN))
                    return 0;
            break;  
    }

    return CallWindowProc(oldWndProcPtr, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: That said, this is an attempt to answer the question so [isn't 'low quality'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/1364007) - it's conceivable that somebody would accept it as it answers their question: it's self-contained, contains some (possibly working) code, it's not a late answer to a question with lots of other answers, etc. - all that it lacks is an explanation of what it does.